# How to convert arraylist to string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

How to convert arraylist to string in Javascript?

I just want to convert arraylist to string in Javascript.
I have this code.

```
var digitStack = [];
digitStack.push(1);
digitStack.push(2);
digitStack.push(3);
```

and I want to make "123".
Any good ideas do you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with an empty string as the separator

```js
var digitStack = [];
digitStack.push(1);
digitStack.push(2);
digitStack.push(3);
var string = digitStack.join('');

snippet.log(string)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Array.join()` :

```js
var digitStack = [];
digitStack.push(1);
digitStack.push(2);
digitStack.push(3);

var digitStr = digitStack.join('');

console.log(digitStr); // gives you a string.
```

Answer (score 1):

User Arrayname.join();

```
var digitStack = [];
digitStack.push(1);
digitStack.push(2);
digitStack.push(3);

var digitStr = digitStack.join(''); //predefined function

document.write(digitStr); // just to verify the string, it has to be removed later
```